# How to add up all of the elements in a column of a 2d list within a dictionary? Python 3

Tags: python, dictionary, 2d

My code is a dictionary with values that are 2d lists. I need to write a function that will total up all of the same index numbers in each list within the dictionary. Here is what I have so far:

```
def totalQty(theInventory):

totalQuantity = 0

for key in theInventory:
    for book in key:
        totalQuantity += book[3]
```

theInventory is the dictionary , and book is each list stored in the dictionary. I keep getting this error:

```
builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a dict `for key in theInventory` doesn't give you each element but the key for each element, so you have to access the element via `theInventory[key]`

you could also use `for key, value in theInentory.items()`. Then you can iterate over `value`.

Try:

```
for key, value in theInventory.items():
    for book in value:
        totalQuantity += int(book[3])
```

Comment: I'm getting:   builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: what is in `book[3]`? something like `1` or `'1'`?

Comment: book[3] is just an integer from a file, so should be just 1

Comment: should be? Have you checked it?

Comment: Ok I was confused it is actually '1'. How can I fix that?

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for all of the confusion, I am kinda new to this

Answer (score 0):

```
def totalQty(theInventory):
totalQuantity = 0
for key in theInventory:
    totalQuantity += theInventory[key][3]
```

The key variable is a string of the key name not a list